# Wordpress: if meta = true AND meta = true

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I want to show a symbol as a separator between two meta fields but only when both are present — often only one will be in use, in which case I don't want to show the separator.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
<?php if ( get_post_meta($related->ID, 'author', true && $related->ID, 'photographer', true)) : ?>
```

I think the problem lies in the brackets but I've tried a ton of variations and can't get it to work. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the function twice to make this kind of comparison. The only thing that can be passed with a function are arguments.

```
<?php if ( get_post_meta($related->ID, 'author', true) && get_post_meta($related->ID, 'photographer', true)) : ?>
```

Comment: Beware, this will be `true` if there's a value, regardless of value.

Comment: @Rob - care to explain? get_post_meta returns a string if param 3 is `true`. Type juggling plays a role here.

Comment: And an empty string evaluates to false.